# RoR, Passing a variable into view gives a null object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, variables

I am setting a variable in my controller but for some reason it is not getting set.  I tried it two ways.

```
  def update
 #   @available_cars = Car_info.where("user_id = ?", session[:user_id])
    @available_cars = Car_info.find_by_user_id(session[:user_id])
  end
```

In my view I do this.

```
<% @available_cars.each do |car| %>
<%= car.name %>
<% end %>
```

What I intend to do is populate the @available_cars into a drop down list but I can't even get them to print.  I know the session[:user_id] is set because I print it and access it elsewhere.

I get this error...
Expected D:/RailsProjects/mileage/app/models/car_info.rb to define Car_info

in my controller
app/controllers/active_car_controller.rb:6:in `update'

Any help would be appreciated.  New to RoR.

Comment: Change this **Car_info.find_by_user_id(session[:user_id])** to **Car_info.find_by_user_id!(session[:user_id])** and see what error it gives you. Also, you **should not** name classes using underscores.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing this in the right controller action?  update is usually the PUT action associated with a corresponding 'edit' GET view.  Perhaps you ment to do this in the 'edit' method?

Comment: @MauricioLinhares Thanks for the input.  Car_info is the name of the model that was automatically created using the built in scaffolding.  Could this be why I get the following error?

Comment: Expected D:/RailsProjects/mileage/app/models/car_info.rb to define Car_info

Comment: app/controllers/active_car_controller.rb:6:in `update'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your query to:

```
@available_cars = Car_info.find_all_by_user_id(session[:user_id])
```

The `find_all` part will get you all records, whereas `find` only gets you the first. Another way to write this is:

```
@available_cars = Car_info.where("user_id = ?", session[:user_id])
```

Ideally, you want your class to be called `CarInfo`, not `Car_info`.

Comment: car_info was the model it created using the scaffolding.

Comment: The root issue after I fixed the spelling error was the fact I was using Car_info instead of CarInfo as mentioned here.  I didn't realize it was not the same as the model.  Thanks everyone for the help. There were really two errors in my code.  Both these answers were correct.  Sorry I can't mark them as such.  I am so low I can't even mark the other helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I see your controller method is named 'udpate' instead of 'update' - could that be your problem?

Comment: See Above still can't access the variable but it is not a null error.